# How Can I resolve Amasty\Base compatible with Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter::format(array $record) In MAgento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, setup-di-compile, monolog

I upgrade Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.5 and here I get this error at compilation time so how can I resolve this error?

[image]

[image]

I try to compile and indexer.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this file you have to change 1 line

You have to replace your public function line as below.

```
public function format(array $record): string
```

Also check updated file code as below. Please copy and paste following code in your file and check.

```
<?php
/**
* @author Amasty Team
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2022 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
* @package Magento 2 Base Package
*/

namespace Amasty\Base\Debug\System;

class AmastyFormatter extends \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
{
    /**
     * @param array $record
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function format(array $record): string
    {
        $output = $this->format;
        $output = str_replace('%datetime%', date('H:i d/m/Y'), $output);
        $output = str_replace('%message%', $record['message'], $output);
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Hope it'll be useful to you.
Thank you.

Comment: This error resolve for that function but now some other error related to monolog present in weltpixel module can you please help me how can i resolve that

Comment: Yes please create new question and share question url. so i will check and update you accordingly.

Comment: Please download Weltpixel_Backend latest module. Then replace with your current module and check because weltpixel remove logger.php file on that latest version of module.